# Selecting the first non 0 value in a row

Tags: r

I have a large data frame of data from across months and I want to select the 
first number that is not NA in each row. For instance ID 895 would correspond to the value in Feb15, 687.

```
  ID    Jan15   Feb15   Mar15   Apr15  
 ----- ------- ------- ------- ------- 
  100   NA      NA      NA      625    
  113   451     586     NA      NA     
  895   NA      687     313     17  
  454   NA      977     NA      146
```

It would be helpful to store them in a variable so I could perform further calculations by month.

```
apply(tempdat[,32:43],1, function(x) head(which(x>0),1))
```

This data frame contains thousands of rows so, is it possible to have the all the numbers returned for each month stored into their own new vars or one new data frame by month.

In this case:

```
AggJan15 = 451
AggFeb15 = 687
AggMar15 = 0 
AggApr15 = 625
```

Comment: You are using `NA` and `0` interchangeably, but in R they are very different.

Comment: What should happen when two IDs have the same value as the first non-NA value?

Comment: Both first values for the row can be added into one variable.

Comment: I am using them interchangeably which is bad practice but it is easy to switch back and forth if need be.

Comment: Do you mean summing them?

Comment: Yeah summing, so in the updated description the agg variable for Feb15 would be 687 + 977

Answer (score 1):

The two answers below are based on different assumptions on what the question is saying.

**1)** In this answer we are assuming you want the first non-NA in each row.  First find the index of the first NAs, one per row, using `max.col` giving `ix`.  Then create an output data frame whose first column is `ID`, second is the first non-NA month for that row and whose third column is the value in that month.  The next line NAs out any month that does not have a non-NA value and is not needed if you know that every row has at least one non-NA.  Note that we have convert month/year to class `yearmon` so that they sort properly.

```
library(zoo)

DF1 <- DF[-1]
ix <- max.col(!is.na(DF1), "first")
out <- data.frame(ID = DF$ID, 
                  month = as.yearmon(names(DF1)[ix], "%b%y"),
                  value = DF1[cbind(1:nrow(DF1), ix)])
out$month[is.na(out$value)] <- NA

##    ID    month value
## 1 100 Apr 2015   625
## 2 113 Jan 2015   451
## 3 895 Feb 2015   687
```

In a comment the poster says they want the sum by month so in that case we first sum by month giving `ag` and then we merge that with all months within the range to fill it out.  The third line can be omitted if it is OK to have absent months filled in with NA; otherwise, use it and they will be filled with 0.

```
ag <- aggregate(value ~ month, out, sum)
m <- merge(ag, seq(min(ag$month), max(ag$month), 1/12), by = 1, all = TRUE)
m$value[is.na(m$value)] <- 0

##      month value
## 1 Jan 2015   451
## 2 Feb 2015   687
## 3 Mar 2015     0
## 4 Apr 2015   625
```

**2)** Originally I thought you wanted the first non-NA in each column and this answer addresses that.

Assuming `DF` is as shown reproducibly in the Note at the end use `na.locf` specifying reverse order and take the first row.

```
library(zoo)

Agg <- na.locf(DF[-1], fromLast = TRUE)[1, ]

Agg
##   Jan15 Feb15 Mar15 Apr15
## 1   451   586   313   625

Agg$Jan15
## [1] 451
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "ID    Jan15   Feb15   Mar15   Apr15  
 ----- ------- ------- ------- ------- 
  100   NA      NA      NA      625    
  113   451     586     NA      NA     
  895   NA      687     313     17     "
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, comment.char = "-")
```